# English equivalent of a Malayalam saying "In the land where no one has a nose, the broken-nosed one is the king"

Tags: phrase-requests, proverbs

There is a saying in Malayalam which can be roughly translated as "In the land where no one has a nose, the broken-nosed one is the king". Is there a way to express the same sentiment in English?

Comment: Chinese version: 山中无老虎，猴子称大王。

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The customary saying is **In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king,** which was apparently [coined by Erasmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desiderius_Erasmus#Writings).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and for leading me to other phrases coined by this Erasmus dude ...

Comment: is there any word or adjective to describe such a person ?

Comment: @Samhan Not without context. If you really want a single word or adjective, please edit your question to include the context. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_land_of_the_blind,_the_one-eyed_man_is_king) has a couple of scenarios, in which number 2 could be rather sarcastic -- which would influence the choice of word.

Comment: There's a phrase - _a big fish in a small pond_.

Comment: It would not surprise me if Erasmus were in fact the origin of the Malayalam saying.

Comment: I wonder what it is about Malayalam speakers that makes them think powers of olfactory discrimination are more relevant to social advancement than the ability to see. Is it maybe that at least the broken-nosed man can still sniff out corruption in "high" places?

Comment: Let me recommend the H.G. Wells story ["The Country of the Blind"](http://www.online-literature.com/wellshg/3/), which takes off from the Latin proverb.

Comment: yea its possible that Erasmus is the source of the saying.

Comment: powers of olfactory discrimination ... im stealing that one ..

Comment: but the proverb isnt referring to the sense of smell per se. The sense is that normally a person with a crushed nose would rank among the worst in terms of looks . But where noone has a nose he would be the best.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth A big fish is not an analogy for someone with a broken nose. A big fish is at a high level, just maybe not the highest, since it's hard to tell when there are only a few normal people around.

Comment: @user47014 I don't agree. 'Big' etc are pragmatically usually used deictically. A big ant is smaller than a small elephant. It's normally considered to be tiny.  'A big fish in a small pond' is a fixed expression; further, it is an idiom meaning 'someone who's top [in/at something]  "in a minor league", but wouldn't be able to compete in the big wide world / 'sea' / whale shark pen'. The star footballer at Mountain Valley High, but not La Liga material. /// The 'broken nose' / 'one eye' adages are hyperbolic.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth that's not what big fish in a small pond means, it means the person might be good in the big leagues but you don't know because the pond is small. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+fish+in+a+small+pond  and the one eye adage means someone with known limited abilities  https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_land_of_the_blind,_the_one-eyed_man_is_king  so big and having one eye are describing different scenarios

Comment: @user47014 One of the definitions there is 'An individual who is important or prominent only in a small group.'  And another gives the narrower definition 'It often implies that the person may not have as much clout in "a bigger pond"' as a possibility. You're saying that "Because X can mean A, it can't mean B (even though some authorities say it can).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth yes "may not" are the key words here, and they are only important in a small group because they haven't tried joining the bigger one yet. So you don't know if it's an ant or an elephant.  None of the definitions say the person has known limited abilities, like the one eye analogy.

Comment: @user47014 'An individual who is important only in a small group' entails that they are of little importance in a larger group. That means they're limited.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth You can try to bend the meaning of the term all you want, but its meaning doesn't apply here. They aren't part of the larger group so you can't say they are little importance in it, they may or may not be, you don't know until they join it. And even if they were of little importance in a larger group, they still excel at what they do in their small group, hence they are extraordinary at least, maybe just not the most extraordinary, but still not mediocre. A small group is still a random sampling of normal people, so you still have to be above mediocre to stand out in it.