# Is there an idiom for the situation where no extraordinary people are available but mediocre ones?

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for an equivalent of a Chinese saying "If there are no great generals left in *Shu*, *Liao Hua* (a military general of Shu) will be the vanguard."

It can be interpreted as "the state of *Shu* lacked great talents and new blood so that they had to let the elderly *Liao Hua* to fight in the vanguard". It is basically a situation where an unfit person is forced into a job because no one suitable can be found.

Comment: You could say, "we make do with what we have" but I don't think I'd call it an idiom, and not necessarily about only people.

Comment: You could say "We had to take Hobson's choice".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English equivalent of a Malayalam saying "In the land where no one has a nose, the broken-nosed one is the king"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101204/english-equivalent-of-a-malayalam-saying-in-the-land-where-no-one-has-a-nose-t) (where 'In the land of the blind ...' from Erasmus, and 'a big fish in a small pond' are given.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Neither of those fit exactly. It isn't about one only one mediocre person being around amongst many totally inept people; many mediocre people may be available, it's just that no extraordinary people are around. And a big fish is an at least somewhat extraordinary person, around some ordinary folk.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I think "In the land of the blind..." is the closest I found so far although not exactly an equivalent.

Comment: "In the land of the blind..." is more an equivalent to another Chinese saying "the monkeys reign when there are no tigers in the mountain".

Comment: @user47014  I was really hoping to discourage bloatware in the form of repeat not-quite-equivalent suggestions.

Comment: The French expression *faute de mieux* can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

“In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king”

This is of [great vintage](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_land_of_the_blind,_the_one-eyed_man_is_king) and its similarity to that in the question should be self-evident, although it is not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that it is not exactly equivalent, but I think this is the closest one I got so far :)